# How to fix the file does not exist error with read_csv in Python?

Tags: python, sql

Sorry for providing the large code here. I am not sure where the real problem is. I want to transfer data from multiple csv files compressed within tar.gz file to the SQL server. Each csv file should be a table in SQL server.

```
import sqlalchemy, pyodbc, zipfile, os, gzip,tarfile, pandas 
from StringIO import StringIO
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:...This is correct, I checked!')
infile="mysql-2016-09-05.tar.gz"
def linecount(infile, member):
    lc = 0
    with gzip.GzipFile(infile) as zipf:
        with tarfile.TarFile(fileobj=zipf) as tarf:
            dataf = tarf.extractfile(member)
            while dataf.readline():
               lc += 1 
            dataf.close()       
    return lc

chunksize = 10000

os.chdir("from file path: This is correct, I checked!")
tar = tarfile.open(infile)

for member in tar.getnames():
    if member.endswith("csv"):
        nlines=linecount(infile,member)    
        for i in range(0, nlines, chunksize):
            df = pandas.read_csv(member,sep=',', nrows=chunksize, skiprows=i)
            filename=member.split("/")[1]
            df.to_sql(filename, engine, if_exists='append',index= False, index_label=None, chunksize=chunksize)
    else:
        continue

tar.close()
engine.dispose()
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                              
  File "tar3.py", line 26, in <module>                                                                                                                                          
  df = pandas.read_csv(member,sep=',', nrows=chunksize, skiprows=i)
  .
  .
  IOError: File mysql-2016-09-05/commit_comments.csv does not exist
```

Please advise the fix. Thanks!

Comment: Try using the [getmembers method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018512/reading-tar-file-contents-without-untarring-it-in-python-script)

Comment: what do you get when you print `tar.getnames()`

Comment: I get a list of file names compressed inside the "mysql-2016-09-05.tar.gz" file. To be exact, I get this list ['mysql-2016-09-05',  'mysql-2016-09-05/commit_comments.csv', ... 'mysql-2016-09-05/ght-restore-mysql',
 'mysql-2016-09-05/project_languages.csv']