# Problems uploading a .tar file

Tags: python, file, google-colaboratory, file-format

I am working with a file in .tar.Z format. I manually changed its name so it would only have the .tar extension, and I'm currently struggling to open it and read the data. I can't seem to find what did I do wrong.

```
!pip install tslearn  #Library for Time Series

!pip install hmmlearn  #Library for Hidden Markov Models

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time # For optimization purposes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import pylab as pl
import io

from google.colab import drive

#Jupyter notebook option for display
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
%matplotlib inline

filename='diabetes-data'

uploaded = files.upload()

columnsNames = [
    'sequenceName',
    'TagIdentificator',
    'timestamp',
    'dateFORMAT',
    'x-coordinate-of-the-tag',
    'y-coordinate-of-the-tag',
    'z-coordinate-of-the-tag',
    'activity'
]

data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded[filename]+'.tar'),encoding='latin1',header=None,names=columnsNames)
```

I did some research and ended up adding the "encoding='latin1' when an error about character reading occurred, but I have no idea how to solve this one.
Thank you so much!

Comment: A tar file is a binary file; you should use the `tarfile` library to open it, not try to read it as character data. Tangentially perhaps see also [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chararcter-encoding/info) which explains character encodings in some more detail. Renaming the file only confuses yourself; you want to put back the `.Z` extension to remind yourself of the actual type of the file (it is a `.tar.Z` file, not a `.tar` file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018512/reading-tar-file-contents-without-untarring-it-in-python-script

Comment: Sidenote on your first few lines of code in your post .... You should be using current best practice for running install commands inside notebooks, namely `%pip install <package_name>`. You'll have a better experience going forward using that because the magic install commands insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel that is backing the active `.ipynb` file is running. Use of an exclamation point alone doesn't do this. More at top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). ...

Comment: <continued sidenote> See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install`, the latter being preferred if you are using Anaconda/conda as your **primary package manager** because you installed Anaconda/conda.

Answer (score 0):

tar.Z indicates it is not just a tar file but it is additionally compressed. As far as I know it is a zip compression.
You might need unzip additionally.

Comment: No, `.Z` is the legacy `compress` utility. This fails to address the OP's more fundamental misunderstanding; they appear to think there is a way to read the tar file as a CSV file directly.