# I instal graphviz to use in Jupyter through anaconda but it keeps showing the error below

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

!pip install graphviz

!pip install pydot

import sys

import os

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'D:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'

sys.path

Comment: "I instal graphviz to use in Jupyter through anaconda ..." ?? The commands you show for installing are not for installing through Anaconda/conda. You show pip installs which aren't able to install some dependencies needed whereas Anacoan/conda will have more chance of having the ability to install them better. The commands to run in the notebook would be `%conda install conda-forge::python-graphviz` (Or `%conda install -c conda-forge pygraphviz`?). Base on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33433735/8508004). And `%conda install conda-forge::pydot`. Restart the kernel after those complete.

Comment: Whether you are using `pip` or `conda` you should be using the magic install commands to install when running inside an active `.ipynb` file. See my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751756/problems-uploading-a-tar-file#comment137073811_77751756) as to why you don't want to be using the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands any more. And you can use whether advice suggest the magic install commands vs. the outdated exclamation point as a gauge for sources of current advice.